Find a way to send output of program1 as input to program2 in python
Can someone help me find a way to send the output of program1 as input to program2 in Python?
Saving it as a .csv file wont help me because the program is supposed to perform those tasks as fast as possible...
Therefore I'm looking for a way to directly send terminal output of program1 into program2.

do you need the results from program1 to be sent to program2 while program1 is still running?

Saving data to .csv (unless it's millions of data) and reading .csv takes approx. half a second. Where is the issue here? For multithread communication I would go with C++.
Going via file is one option here.  It is definitely option to go via Pipes "Popen" from subprocess.

another option is to use sockets for interprocess communication. If program1 has a lot of print statements and it would be too much work to change all of them, you can rebind sys.stdout to a file-like object that wraps the socket

Use program1.py | program2.py to communicate. Use sys.stdout and sys.stdin to implement the communication.
